# Retain the headers and footers at the start of the document in officedown while using <!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->/<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->?

Tags: r, r-markdown, officer, officedown

I'm currently generating a Word document using Rmarkdown and the officedown package. I'm using a reference document to set the styles and assign headers and footers on the document. This also includes a different header and footer on the first page.

My problem is that there is a part in my document that needs to be in landscape. But when I use the `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->` and `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->`, the headers and footers start to appear only after the `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->`.

On the sample below, the headers and footers only appears starting at the # Results.

```
---
title: "My Document"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: path/to/reference.docx
---

# Introduction

This is the introduction section.

# Methods

This is the methods section.

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->

# Landscape Section 1

This is the content of the first landscape section.

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->

# Results

This is the results section.

# Conclusion

This is the conclusion section.
```

I've been looking through the github repository of `officedown` as well as the documentation for the possible solution but I'm still having this issue.

I tried updating package to an earlier version as well as the latest version but I still got the same result so I'm not sure if this can be fixed.

Here are some solutions that I can think of if this can't be fixed but I can't try to figure out how:

1. Re-apply the template once the Word file was generated. This does not need to be on the Rmarkdown code itself but can also be on a external R program. I'm not sure if this is possible but I've been looking for a way to do this both in R and Python.
2. I've read the comment on the git repository [here](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/issues/99#issuecomment-1436587437) but I've read the documentation on `prop_section()` and I can't seem to find the part where I can add a custom header or footer. I need to add a different header/footer on the first page and a different header/footer on the succeeding page. The headers/footers also have different formatting/alignment and contains shape objects.
3. A bit similar to #1, after the Word file has been generated, open the Word file in R(or possible python) and look for the page with a specific header and change it's orientation to landscape.

Comment: See my answer to this in officedown repo, I think it answer your questions  https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/issues/105#issuecomment-1464036392.